# Passing the value of a bound list

Tags: windows-phone-7

I had this code working before, but have somehow deleted it as I was trying to get something else fixed.

So I have a list which is bound as a View model, and the list has three lines on it.

I want to be able to click on the list, get the value of the third line on another page and use that value.

Here is the code for the selection of the list

```cs
private void List_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

        // If selected index is -1 (no selection) do nothing
        if (List.SelectedIndex == -1)
            return;

        // Navigate to the new page
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Route.xaml?selectedItem=" + List.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));

        string urlWIthData = string.Format("/Route.xaml?name={0}", " ");
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(urlWIthData, UriKind.Relative));
        // Reset selected index to -1 (no selection)
        List.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Then, on the route page I want to be able to get the value and use the value line three....

How do I do this?

EDIT:

so this one part of the list:

```cs
this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "Images/1.png", LineTwo = "Whitehawk - County   
Hospital - City Centre - Hove - Portslade - Mile Oak", LineThree = "1 Whitehawk - Mile Oak", 
LineFour = "1 Mile Oak - Whitehawk", LineFive = "1149" });
```

I Display the list on one page :

```xml
 <ListBox Margin="6,6,7,6" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Name="List" OpacityMask="#FFD38648" FontSize="26" SelectionChanged="List_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17" DataContext="{Binding}">
                        <Image Name="Images" Source="{Binding LineOne}">
                        </Image>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Name="textblock3"></TextBlock>
                                             </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Is the third item something specific, or just an example of if you click on the third item, that's what you want to send to the next page?

Comment: Hi, yes. It's a list of routes, the first item is an image, the second description and the third is a code, which is used in a url to get another list.

So at the moment Item one and two are displayed on the first page. Wehrn the user clicks on that, it goes to another page (as seen in the code above) but I want to get find that and get the third line. Will add more info above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the list's SelectedItem to type Item and get the value from there:

```cs
private void List_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
       // If selected index is -1 (no selection) do nothing
        if (List.SelectedIndex == -1)
            return;

       // Here's the codes -----------------------

       var item = Items.SelectedItem as Item;
       if(item == null) //cast didn't work
            return;

       var lineThree = item.LIneThree;

       // end of the codes -----------------------

        // Navigate to the new page
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Route.xaml?selectedItem=" + List.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));

        string urlWIthData = string.Format("/Route.xaml?name={0}", " ");
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(urlWIthData, UriKind.Relative));
        // Reset selected index to -1 (no selection)
        List.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```